# Unable to load the Packed bubble chart of highcharts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm encountering an issue with rendering the `PackedBubbleChart` component in my React TypeScript application. When attempting to load the page, it breaks with a console error, and I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue.

Details:

Highcharts version: 11.4.0
React Highcharts version: 16.1.0
Additional modules: highcharts-more, highcharts/modules/exporting, highcharts/modules/accessibility, highcharts/modules/annotations

**Issue**:
When attempting to load the page, I encounter the following error in the console.
I've ensured that all dependencies are correctly installed and imported. Could someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?
I am using "highcharts": "^11.4.0", "react-highcharts": "^16.1.0","highcharts-more": "^0.1.7".

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import HC_more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import Accessible from 'highcharts/modules/accessibility';
import AnnotationsChart from 'highcharts/modules/annotations';

// Initialize Highcharts More module
HC_more(Highcharts); 
Exporting(Highcharts);
Accessible(Highcharts);
AnnotationsChart(Highcharts);

const PackedBubbleChart = () => {
  const config: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'packedbubble',
      height: '100%'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Simple Bar Chart'
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}m CO<sub>2</sub>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      packedbubble: {
        minSize: '30%',
        maxSize: '120%',
        layoutAlgorithm: {
          splitSeries: false,
          gravitationalConstant: 0.02
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.name}',
          filter: {
            property: 'y',
            operator: '>',
            value: 250
          },
          style: {
            color: 'black',
            textOutline: 'none',
            fontWeight: 'normal'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Asia',
      type: 'packedbubble',
      data: [{
        name: 'Nepal',
        value: 6.5
      },
      {
        name: 'Iran',
        value: 6.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Korea',
        value: 6.1
      }]
    }]
  };

  return <ReactHighcharts config={config} />;
};

export default PackedBubbleChart;
```

Using it in other component like:

```
<PackedBubbleChart/>
```

Error:

````
```Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at a.error (highcharts.js:12:237)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:252:415)
    at eval (highcharts.js:277:133)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.each (highcharts.js:31:26)
    at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:277:104)
    at a.Chart.eval (highcharts.js:252:304)
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:33:502)
    at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:251:91)
    at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:251:16)
ReactHighcharts.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')
    at n.value (ReactHighcharts.js:1:3070)
    at n.value (react-hot-loader.development.js:707:1)
    at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (react-dom.development.js:19582:12)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:190:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:239:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:294:31)
    at safelyCallComponentWillUnmount (react-dom.development.js:19589:5)
    at commitUnmount (react-dom.development.js:20111:11)
    at commitNestedUnmounts (react-dom.development.js:20165:5)
    at unmountHostComponents (react-dom.development.js:20445:7)```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using additional modules or plugins with Highcharts, it's important to initialize and extend the Highcharts instance directly as demonstrated below. This ensures that all extended features and functionalities of the modules or plugins are correctly applied and available for use in your charts:

```
return <ReactHighcharts highcharts={Highcharts} config={config} />;
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i am able to render the component. But it's displaying the bubble separately. Actually i want to display the nested bubbles. Like child bubbles are displayed inside their parent bubbles and grandchild bubbles inside child bubbles.

Comment: It depends on your data and chart configuration. Check these examples and adjust your chart for your requirements: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/packed-bubble.

Comment: Yeah i tried with these examples but could not create nested bubbles with more than two levels of hierarchy. Looks like highcharts doesn't support it still.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17684

Comment: That's right. Please vote for this feature request or left the comment if you are interested in that implementation.